# Perl Array handling

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a global array containing elements such as:

```
@myarray = ("A","B","C","D","E");
```

I'm reading a column line by line which has values like:

```
Row1: A
Row2: Z
Row3: B C
Row4: A B C
Row5: A B C Z
Row6: A C
Row7: E
```

1. Problem 1 : If Row1 is read and has "A" which is present in @myarray -> no action required, but in case of Row2 "Z" is not a part of @myarray it should fail with some message.
2. Some rows have multiple elements, it should check for all, for example row3 "A","B","C" all three are part of @myarray --> no action required, but incase of Row4 it should read "A" , "B","C", then comes "Z" which is not a valid element it should fail with some message.

Comment: Please show us your code. Needs [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

First, create a hash so we can easily and efficiently lookup if a value is valid.

```perl
my %ok = map { $_ => 1 } @array;
```

Then, it's just a question of checking if all the values are in the hash.

```perl
while (<>) {
   my ($hdr, $values) = /^([^:]+):\s*(.*)/
      or do {
         warn("Invalid input at \"$ARGV\" line $.\n");
         next;
      };

   my @values = split(' ', $values);
   if ( my @invalid = grep { !$ok{$_} } @values ) {
      warn("Invalid values (@invalid) for $hdr at \"$ARGV\" line $.\n");
      next;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this could help you.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(any);

my @array = qw/A B C D E/;

while(<DATA>){
    chomp($_);
    print "At line -> $_\n";
    my @contents = split(' ', $_);
    
    foreach my $each_element (@contents){
        if (not (any { $_ eq $each_element } @array)) {
            print "$each_element -> Not exists in array\n";
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
A
Z
B C
A B C
A B C Z
A C
E
```

As suggested by @ikegami, this could also work as per the expectation:

```
...
my @array = qw/A B C D E/;

my %skip_hash = map { $_ => 1 } @array;

while(<DATA>){
    chomp($_);
    print "At line -> $_\n";
    my @contents = split(' ', $_);
    
    foreach my $each_element (@contents){
        if (not ($skip_hash{$each_element})) {
            print "$each_element -> Not exists in array\n";
        }
    }
}
```